# "Unable to load any of the alternatives" when using Quicklisp to install CL+SSL even after installing open ssl

Tags: ssl, openssl, common-lisp, quicklisp, asdf

```
[2]> (ql:quickload "cl+ssl")
To load "cl+ssl":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    cl+ssl
; Loading "cl+ssl"

*** - Unable to load any of the alternatives:
      ("libssl32.dll" "ssleay32.dll")
```

After three days of banging my head against the wall, I'm asking my first question on stack overflow. And with any luck it won't get deleted, and with heaps more there will be a solution.

While trying to install Humbler via quicklisp, CL+SSL (one of several dependencies) complained of being "Unable to load any of the alternatives: (libss132.dll "ssleay32.dll")

I soon learned that I had to install the OpenSSL dlls, easily enough done. I also learned I may have to point CFFI in the direction of my dlls, and that I had to be sure to get the 64 bit versions. But that error has persisted.

Using Clisp 2.47 on Win 7 64

Things I have tried already:

- Installing open ssl dlls
- Installing VS 2008 Redist
- Putting those dlls in system32
- Putting them in the same folder as the Clisp .exe
- Putting them in in the installation folder created by OpenSSL
- Pointing to the exact location of each individual dll using "use another library instead" restart
- Pushing various locations to the CFFI:*Foreign-Library-Directories* list

  Break 1 CL+SSL[3]> :R2
  Enter a new value (unevaluated): ("C:\OpenSSL-Win64\libssl32.dll")
  *** - Unable to load foreign library (LIBSSL32.DLL-8079).
    FFI:OPEN-FOREIGN-LIBRARY: Cannot open library "C:\OpenSSL-Win64\libssl32.dll"
- Uninstalling and then installing all the different OpenSSL builds
- available Running Clisp as an administrator  Deleting Quicklisp's
- cache of CL+SSL Doing all of the above steps in SBCL and Lispworks
- Turning it off and on again

I've never asked a question on stack overflow before. Then again I've never spent three days trying to get a dependency to load. Please help before I have a stroke.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: I tried and unfortunately it works fine on my system. Just a guess, sorry if it sounds trivial: did you correctly backslash your backslashes when entering paths (they need to be escaped)?

Comment: Are you sure that you're using 64bit CLISP ? I wasn't able to find CLISP 64bit Windows distribution online, 32bit only on sourceforge. I'd recommend you to double check that. If in fact your CLISP is 32bit than SSL libraries must be 32 bit too. And other binary dependencies too (if there are any).

Comment: Also 2.47 is not the latest available version, It's usually advisible to use the latest version if you don't have good reasons to stick with 2.47.
(Note: I've never used CLISP so my advices are without any practical confirmation from my side.)

Comment: Correction: I'm using 2.49, and there is not a 64 bit version of Clisp, but I have the 64 bit version of windows and read somewhere that I would need the 64 bit version of OpenSSL. I'll try the 32 bit ones

Answer (score 5):

It turns out I did need the 32 bit version of OpenSSL v 1.0.1

I guess the bit depth of the compiler reigns supreme. Sounds obvious in retrospect.